# 'X-Frame-Options' headers with conflicting values when tried to import products

Tags: magento-2.1, admin, import

I have a problem when I tried to import products with a CSV. The loading gif stay spinning and nothing happens. The page don´t show any error. I first thought that could be permissions problem, but I changed all permissions to **777** and the error persists.

Now in Chrome Console and Firebug, I see the next error:

```
Refused to display 'http://[site]/admin/admin/import/validate/key/bda6ac49ba7066862dd8fe30ca58ded2bffa852bd62c2e7cd43c6971dcf2bcaf/?form_key=xarU1fpOx0MQZPfT' in a frame because it set multiple 'X-Frame-Options' headers with conflicting values ('DENY, SAMEORIGIN'). Falling back to 'deny'.
POST http://[site]/admin/admin/import/validate/key/bda6ac49ba7066862dd8fe30ca58ded2bffa852bd62c2e7cd43c6971dcf2bcaf/?form_key=xarU1fpOx0MQZPfT net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE
```

In some pages said that it could be by the **x-frame-options** value defined in **app/etc/env.php**. My current value is **SAMEORIGIN**:

```
'x-frame-options' => 'SAMEORIGIN',
```

What value it must be?

Thanks!

**EDIT 1: ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**
Reviewing the headers of the request of my site, I saw that in every page, nos only Admin, the header **X-Frame-Options** is duplicated with different values:

```
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Frame-Options:DENY
```

What could make this happens?

Answer (score 11):

Well, after so much research in code and configuration, I determined that the second header **X-Frame-Options:DENY** was nos declared in Magento. So, I review my others Magento and no Magento sites, and I noticed that every sites had the same header. So, the logical option was Apache.

I made a *grep* in Apache2 configurations, and I found a **Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY** in **/etc/apache2/conf-available/ssl-params.conf** I commented that line, restarted Apache, and surprise, the imports works fine, and I only see one **X-Frame-Options** header in the requests.

I don´t know if is a good practice comment that line. Someone with more expertise in that area could tell me more about. But, until that, this fix my problem. So, if someone is fighting with something similar, I recommend you look in the configuration of the server, to see if there is something that is inserting again the same header, additional to that of Magento.

Comment: This was a problem for me too, in Wordpress. You are a life saver, I'm leaving this comment so that google indexes it and helps save someone else.

Comment: Thank you! I'd used the below link to setup a local SSL, which included the X-Frame DENY config.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-apache-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Finally I found the answer for my question, works like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

@eliacim-davila-censere's [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/189992/2294) works fine. I think its more secure to set this value to `SAMEORIGIN` so that iframes only from same domain can work.

In `/etc/apache2/conf-available/ssl-params.conf` change

`Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY`

to

`Header always set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN`